# Why do I get SIGKILL instead of std::bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, linux, exception, memory

My 16GB machine behaves as if it's out of memory (applications report allocation failures, ksqwapd goes crazy despite no swap partition mounted) even though system monitors such as `top` report there is plenty of memory available.

So I wrote this program to allocate memory to exhaustion and report the amount allocated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

const size_t STRIDE = 64;

int main ()
{
    for (size_t n = 0; ; ++n)
    {
        try
        {
            char * ptr = new char [1024*1024];

            for (char * p = ptr; p < ptr + 1024*1024; p += STRIDE)
            {
                *p = 123;
            }

            if (n > 0 && 0 == (n % 1024))
            {
                std :: cout << (n / 1024) << "   GiB" << std :: endl;
            }
            else if (n > 0 && 0 == (n % 512))
            {
                std :: cout << (n / 1024) << ".5 GiB" << std :: endl;
            }
        }
        catch (const std :: exception & e)
        {
            std :: cout << n << "MiB total" << std :: endl;
            std :: cout << "Caught: " << e .what () << std :: endl;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std :: cout << n << "MiB total" << std :: endl;
            std :: cout << "Caught exception." << std :: endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I ran this program with over 10GiB of reported available memory, it received `SIGKILL` after counting to 2GiB. Why would it receive a signal instead of throwing an exception?

Also, any idea why it only got to 2GiB? I ran it again after rebooting and it got to 13GiB (it should have got as far as 13.5GiB, since `top` reports 13.9GiB available). What might stop all available memory from being granted?

Ubuntu with kernel 4.2.0-42-generic.

**Edit:* /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory is 0 (heuristic overcommit) but this doesn't explain why *other* programs seem to capture out-of-memory as an exception rather than being killed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779042/sigkill-while-allocating-memory-in-c

Comment: http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/40 here is also described memory limits per process and mentioned that linux sends a SIGKILL when one gets reached.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall the answer there seems to be about not enough memory being available on the system. This seems not the case here.

Comment: Check with the command "ulimit -a" if there is any limitation on the amount of memory for the process.